# Rails, custom controller methods do you use one or two methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My apps has two models: `Group` & `GroupMembers`

In the GroupMembers controller I have a method `leave_group`

I use the leave_group method on get to populate a dialog to confirm. Then on post I post back to the same method.

Is that the right way to do it? Use one method for both get and put? Or do you create two?

If you should use one method who do you know which is which inside the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Definitely use two methods if you have to do it this way. Having logic in your controller to determine what to do based on the request type will make your application a pain to debug when something goes wrong. Plus, if you start doing this all over the place, you will soon forget how you designed it.

I always follow the REST pattern where possible. This makes it so you don't have to think about what your controller is doing in each action. REST is not always the best option, which may be true in your case. If you really must break from this pattern, I would name each method exactly what it is doing. If one is just returning a message, call it `leave_group_confirm_message` or something like that. The other one you could call `leave_group` since that is the action it is performing.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 methods, but route them based on request type in the routes file.  This is basically what the standard new and create methods do -- same endpoint, but one takes get, one post.

So, something like this:

```
match "membership_details" => "group_members#show", :via => :get
match "membership_details" => "group_members#leave_group", :via => :post
```

You could also pull out the membership into a many-to-many relationship that you can explicitly get (your first method) and delete (your second method).  Not saying this is the right way to go, but worth considering.

In this case you would do something like:

```
resources :users do 
    resources :membership :only => [:show, :destroy]
end
```